# \begin{table} incompatible with graphicx?

Tags: tables

I used to import tables from R program using the LaTeX commands that R spins out in the `xtable`-package. It involves commands like:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{{ rr }}
  \hline
 &  \\ 
  \hline
```

The moment I included the command: `\usepackage{graphicx}`, it shows that the command `\begin{tabular}` is an illegal character and the output in the table vanishes. The problem persists even when I remove the command: `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

Comment: you should expand your MWE to showhow you're using the code and packages. btw: your example's missing the `\end{}` clauses in both cases you've shown.

Comment: Did you put it in your preamble (before `\begin{document}`)?

Comment: You don't need `graphicx` for tables at all.

Comment: Thanks all. I had a previous version saved so I am saved for now, although do want to know the answer for future work;naphaneal:the end was there, I haven't shown the entire code; Jeffrey:first after, then before, then didn't include it at all, but the problem persisted; Christian: thanks, I didn't know it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot group multiple columns within the `tabular` column specification. Moreover, it's not needed. So, instead of

```
\begin{tabular}{ {rr} }
  <tabular body>
\end{tabular}
```

just use

```
\begin{tabular}{ r r }
  <tabular body>
\end{tabular}
```